# PHP MySQL Script Error?

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following PHP code that I can't seem to get working. I have looked over and over again for the error(s), but can't find it/them.

```
<?php
$actkey = rand() . "\n";
$con = mysql_connect("HOST", "USER", "PASS");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Unable to connect:  ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("TABLE", $con);

mysql_query("UPDATE members SET Activation = $actkey WHERE username = 'admin'");
mysql_close($con)

$con2 = mysql_connect("HOST" , "USER" , "PASS");
if (!$con2)
  {
  die('Unable to connect:  ' . mysql_error());
  }
mysql_select_db("a1719745_insaneb", $con2);
$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO Activation (keycode, valid) VALUES ($actkey, 'yes')");
if(!mysql_query($query, $con2)) {
  die('Error:  ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_close($con2);
echo "Complete";
?>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: There's a missing semicolon after `mysql_close($con)`.

Comment: What specifically is not working? Turn on your error reporting too.

Comment: @Brian  Thanks! I looked over that code for hours and didn't see it. What would anyone do without Stackoverflow? +1 for you! Would you be willing to post your answer so I may mark it as accepted?

Comment: You really should turn on error reporting in development... can easily avoid errors like this.

Comment: Sometimes I ask the same thing @Zachary Brown :D I already have 50 questions and almost all have been answered successfully.

Comment: @Russell Dias  I am not a great PHP programmer right now, I'm just learning. What are you talking about Debugger? Where can I get one? I Python, the interpreter checks syntax and stuff like that, so I'm not used to needing to debug. :)

Comment: No, I mean error reporting as in the PHP functions. e.g. `error_reporting(-1);` Have a look through the PHP docs for more info =)

Comment: Ok, great! Thanks. This will probably save me hours! +1 for you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a missing semicolon after `mysql_close($con)`.